# USMT excluding this computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, user-accounts, migration

i'm trying to use USMT to migrate user profiles from one system to another.

Here's the command i'm using:

> ```
> C:\USMT\amd64\scanstate.exe F:\Profile /ue:DOMAIN\* /ue:%computername%\* /ui:DOMAIN\username /tel:off /i:C:\USMT\amd64\migapp.xml /i:c:\USMT\amd64\migdocs.xml /o
> ```

I only want to capture one user, which will be specified on /ui:

I would like to exclude "this computer" but you see below it still gathers data for This Computer.

> Log messages are being sent to 'H:\USMT\scanstate.log'
>
> Starting the migration process Processing the settings store
>
> Examining the system to discover the migration units
>   domain\username (1 of 2): 100% done
>   This Computer (2 of 2): 100% done
>
> Selecting migration units
>
> Gathering data    domain\username (1 of 2): 100% done
>   This Computer (2 of 2):   1% done

Any ideas on how to exclude this?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

create a custom XML file with the following contents to exclude the C: drive

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560762(v=ws.10)#ExTwo)

```
<migration urlid="http://www.microsoft.com/migration/1.0/migxmlext/allfiles">
    <component type="Documents" context="System">
        <displayName>Test</displayName>
        <role role="Data">
            <rules>
  <unconditionalExclude>
                    <objectSet>
      <pattern type="File">c:\*[*]</pattern>
                    </objectSet>
  </unconditionalExclude>
            </rules>
        </role>
    </component>
</migration>
```